# Android in MVVM not receiving data from server

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, rx-java2

When I am using MVVM architecture and in this function not working I mean not receiving data from a server but the server is responding here is my function

```
           api.getBitcoinNews(q, from, sortBy, key)
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribeWith(object :DisposableSingleObserver<List<News>>(){
                   override fun onSuccess(t: List<News>) {
                       Log.d(TAG, t.size.toString())
                   }
                   override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

                   }
               })
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you use retrofit? If yes i'm recommended to use logging-interceptor for debugging check this for implementation https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/README.md
Hope this helpful

Comment: Yes I am using retrofit and also interceptor also the problem is with viewmodel

Comment: you can log error in onerror like this: override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

 e.printStackTrace() }